# How to update this aggregate in DDD way using hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, domain-driven-design

I have this situation:

```
@Entity
public class AggregateA {
    private String fieldA;  
    //around 15 simple fields similar to fieldA

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entityFieldA", fetchType= FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<EntityA> entitiesList;
    
    void updateAggregate() {
       //chose appropriate entity from the list and delegate updating to the `EntityA` class.
       EntityA ent = getSomehow();
       ent.updateField2();
    }
}

@Entity
class EntityA {
    private String entityFieldA;
    private String entityFieldB;
    //few more simple fields here

    void updateField2() {
       //set appropriate field
    }
}
```

I would like to update some field inside `EntityA` using `updateAggregate` (because I want to update all entities through aggregate) but the problem is if I fetch aggregate through db, I will fetch those 15 simple fields and also I will have join with entity table and that complicates performance. Before this, there was fairly simple anemic solution. There was repository for EntityA, so we were fetching entitites and update them without aggregate knowing about that update at all. In that case, we were not fetching aggregate, nor with did the join. We only fetched list of entity objects and update them.

I thought maybe spring data projections can help me, but in that case I need to create new interface(with the fields which I want to fetch) and them in that case also I am spreading my business logic on milion places.

Is there any elegant DDD way to solve this? Should I maybe decouple data layer from business DDD layer?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that [Hibernate lazy loading](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-lazy-eager-loading) is what you are looking for.
"Any elegant DDD way to solve it", no solution to this will be from DDD, this is purely a tech issue, DDD tells you what are your entities/aggregates/behaviors, how you reify them in code is not too much part of the DDD world.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Which thing needs to be lazy? I think it is related to the DDD, since if it is pure technical issue, I will just create hibernate repo for EntityA, fetch list of those entities, update them etc. but I don't want to do it that way because then in that case I would update entity without aggregate be aware of that(which should not be done since all entitites should be updated through aggregate).

Comment: You can mark the `entitiesList` in your aggregate as a lazy list in hibernate, so that it will be automatically fetched just when you access it.  
I said it's a tech issue because it is a performance issue, not a model one. What DDD cares about, you said it, changes made from the root, store the aggregate atomically. The problem is the join, an issue that one has because of the technology chosen to store data, and the technology chosen to fetch them.

Comment: I mean solution for this kind of issues can be found looking for the specific technology, not to generic DDD stuffs, as there are a lot of different ways to do this changing the technology used, offering a lot of different solutions.
How I see DDD here is it guides you on choosing the technology features so that its "rules" will be true (eg. an aggregate is stored atomically)

Comment: The trouble is that I need that entityList, to update it, but I don't need data from the aggregate. I only need to fetch entityList, update it and commit it. I don't need to change things related to the root. In that case, lazy cannot help me. And I agree that problem is performance but it seems that in this case I cannot use DDD because of the performance reason.

Comment: ah sorry I got it wrong, thought the issue was the opposite.
that's an interesting issue :) I was thinking if you could make all the other fields in their entity and make it lazy loaded (or look at hibernate's embeddable+lazy loading)

Comment: Re-reading your post you ask about decoupling the domain model from the data layer. That could make sense, and to have a benefit this means that in your domain model you will have an aggregate with less data than this that you can mutate directly (otherwise you will still need to query for everything). 
But in that case maybe you can split your aggregate also now, do you need the list to be here to check for invariants, or because then it is easy to query as a "read model"?